# Copy nested directory structure ignoring all directories of a certain name

Tags: rsync, cp

Say I have a big nested directory `projects/` and I want to recursively copy the entire directory excluding any sub-directory with the name `node_modules/` or `env/`.

I don't know how many `node_modules/` or `env/` directories there are and they can be at any level in the `projects/` tree. I.e. there could be a `projects/project-1/env/` and a `projects/project-2/app/node_modules`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
rsync -rv --exclude=node_modules --exclude=env /projects /destination
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that the `--exclude` option worked recursively

Comment: -rv don't work for me. what works for me is using -av --progress. as `rsync -av --progress --exclude="node_modules" --exclude="env" <source> <destination>`